# Angular2/typescript - unexpected array behavior (such as length is 0 when it is really not)

Tags: angular, typescript

FYI I am very new to Angular2 - basically I'm calling a data service that returns a promise of an array of objects, which I bind in my view and loop through them.  It is working great, but I started exploring how to use a infinite scroll which would require me to append onto the array, but I cannot get this to work.

This is how I declare the array in the component (typescript):

```
integrationCollection: IntegrationEntity[] = [];
```

And this is the data service call:

```
this.integrationService.getIntegrations().then(integrationCollection => this.integrationCollection = integrationCollection);
```

And the results are displayed just fine on the page.  But the length property returns 0.. why would this be ??

```
alert('integrationCollection count: ' + this.integrationCollection.length); // returns 0
```

Also, I'm going to need to be able to add to my array for an infinite scroll scenario, so I think I need to be able to concat the array - but this is not working at all (no errors, but nothing is displayed on the page):

```
this.integrationService.getIntegrations().then(integrationCollection => this.integrationCollection.concat(integrationCollection));
```

I think maybe these two problems are related?  I think I'm just missing something fundamental.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: For the first thing, if I had to guess, it's because the alert is triggering before the `getIntegrations()` call is finished.  I'm not sure about the second issue.

Comment: Thanks, got it.  Second issue is because I need to do an assignment:


    `this.integrationService.getIntegrations().then(integrationCollection => this.integrationCollection = this.integrationCollection.concat(integrationCollection));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of async behavior of framework. Change following of your code:

```
this.integrationService.getIntegrations().then(integrationCollection => this.integrationCollection = integrationCollection);
alert('integrationCollection count: ' + this.integrationCollection.length);
```

to:

```
this.integrationService.getIntegrations().then(integrationCollection => {
this.integrationCollection = integrationCollection;
alert('integrationCollection count: ' + this.integrationCollection.length);
 });
```

Do you see the difference? There are other ways as well to bring synchronus behavior in your code when you need i.e. `Observable.forkJoin`. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
integrationCollection => this.integrationCollection.concat(integrationCollection)
```

You probably want to assign the result of the concat somewhere e.g. :

```
integrationCollection => this.integrationCollection = this.integrationCollection.concat(integrationCollection)
```

## More

> But the length property returns 0.. why would this be ??

Most likely an ordering issue. You should check then length *after* the data has actually returned from the server.